# Batch file replace line in text file with new line

Tags: batch-file, replace, find

I want to be able to replace a line in a properties file but i only know part of the line string at any one time

Heres the line i want to replace: `mb.datasource.password=ENC(8dF45fdD)`

with this: `mb.datasource.password=apassword`

What i have just now is this

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "search=mb.datasource.password="
set "replace=mb.datasource.password=apassword"
set "textfile=mb.properties"
set "newfile=mb-new.properties"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
set "line=%%i"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
echo(!line!
endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
```

This ends up giving me mb.datasource.password=apassword=ENC(8fFdeUdK)

I can't just find the full string it needs to only be mb.datasource.password= because the part after the equals changes

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: i think the only way it would be to use regex, and i don't know if you can do that in ordinary batch files.
i have recently worked with CScript, look it up, it can run scripts written in different languages (like js or typescript) as a batch

Comment: Ahh okay, i gave up with the batch and just wrote a quick c# console app to do it instead, thanks anyway for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find until that line and replace with another text file windows batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689045/find-until-that-line-and-replace-with-another-text-file-windows-batch-script)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with batch. I put together a quick script and it worked for me:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

SET SourceFile="mb.properties"
SET OutputFile="mb-new.properties"
SET "FindKey=mb.datasource.password"
SET "NewValue=apassword"

REM Basic parse for INI file format.
(FOR /F "usebackq eol= tokens=1,* delims==" %%A IN (`TYPE %SourceFile%`) DO (

    REM If the key value matches, build the line with the new value.
    REM Otherwise write out the existing value.
    IF /I "%%A"=="%FindKey%" (
        ECHO %%A=%NewValue%
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO %%A=%%B
    )

)) > %OutputFile%

REM Replace old with new.
DEL %SourceFile%
MOVE %OutputFile% %SourceFile%

ENDLOCAL
```

A few notes about the above:

- I assumed basic INI file format.
- The `FOR` loop will skip blank lines so they would be removed from the new output file. There are ways around this using tricks with the `FIND` command if the blanks are needed.
- If you have special chars (`%` or `!` especially) - this *may* cause some problems, but if you have just "normal" text then it should be fine.

Comment: The file is massive so spaces need to be kept for organisation, i also can't guarantee that special characters won't be used